# Joining within a table with ST_Intersects in Postgis

Tags: postgis

I have a table with the below structure:

| geom | name | ownership |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01031... | foo | landlord |
| 01032... | foo | landlord |
| 01033... | baz | landlord |
| 01034... | bar | tenant |
| 01035... | bar | tenant |
| 01036... | bar | tenant |

Landlords own a wide area and tenants own a small section within.

So, the geom of the tenant will at least intersect with the geom of the landlord.

I want to be able to search for a landlord by name, (`select * from table where name = 'foo' and ownership = 'landlord';`) and  get all of the geoms that the landlord owns and get the tenants with geoms inside those geoms.

Likewise, I want to search for a tenant, get all of the buildings they rent and find all of the enclosing landlord geoms.

Conceptually can't get my head around it. Is ST_Intersects the right method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ST_Intersects` is commonly the way to go.

If there is different spatial relationships like a tenant row is always inside of one and only one a landlord row, other methods like `ST_Within` could be better.

As always there are many ways of write that queries. I think that a comprehensible one (but maybe no very performant will be)

```sql
WITH
tenant AS (
    SELECT * from mytable WHERE ownership = 'tenant'
)
, landlord AS (
    SELECT * from mytable WHERE ownership = 'landlord'
)

SELECT
    tenant.name, landlord.name
FROM
    landlord 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tenant
ON ST_Intersects(landlord.geom, tenant.geom)
WHERE 
    landlord.name = 'foo'
;
```

You can use almost the same query for the other question, just invert the order of the join and the where:

```
WITH
tenant AS (
    SELECT * from mytable WHERE ownership = 'tenant'
)
, landlord AS (
    SELECT * from mytable WHERE ownership = 'landlord'
)

SELECT
    tenant.name, landlord.name
FROM
    tenant 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    landlord
ON ST_Intersects(landlord.geom, tenant.geom)
WHERE 
    tenant.name = 'foo'
;
```